# Show differentiability at a point then find differential where $f(x,y) = (x^2, xy+y^2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Show differentiability at a point then find differential where

$f(x,y) = (x^2, xy+y^2)$

Want to show that $f(x,y) = (x^2, xy+y^2)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ and then calculate the differential d$f(a,b)$

**My Thoughts**

$f_x(x,y) = (2x, y)$ and $f_{xx}(x,y) = (2, 0)$

$f_y(x,y) = (0, x+2y)$ and $f_{yy}(x,y) = (0, 2)$

$f_{xy}(x,y) = (0,1) = f_{yx}(x,y)$

At point $(a,b)$ we get that $f_x(a,b) = (2a,b)$ and $f_y(a,b) = (0,a+2b)$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Am I even on the right track? I am really struggling with differentials.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you learned that a function is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous at said point? As far as the differential, what definition of it were you given? When you obtain the partial derivatives and look at the latter, it will be straight-forward to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is a polinomial, so all partials exist and are continuous everywhere, therefore, your function is differentiable. The Fréchet-differential's matrix in the standard basis is $$ DF|_{(a,b)}=\begin{pmatrix} \left.\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)} & \left.\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)} \\ \left.\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)} & \left.\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)} \end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\rac}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
f(x,y)=\rac{x^2,xy+y^2}\\
f_x(x,y)=\rac{2x,y}\\
f_y(x,y)=\rac{0,x+2y}\\
f_{xy}(x,y)=\rac{0,1}\\
f_{yx}(x,y)=\rac{0,1}\\
f_{xy}=f_{yx}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are just beginning with differentials, you can come back to the definition:

$f(a+h_1,b+h_2)=(a^2+2ah_1+h_1^2,ab+ah_2+bh_1+h_1h_2+b^2+2bh_2+h_2^2)$
$=(a^2,ab+b^2)+(2ah_1,ah_2+bh_1+2bh_2)+(h_1^2,h_1h_2+h_2^2)$

Now you can check that $(h_1^2,h_1h_2+h_2^2)$ is composed by second order terms in $h_1, h_2$, and that your differential will be

$(h_1,h_2)\mapsto (2ah_1,ah_2+bh_1+2bh_2)$

so that you have

$f(a+h_1,b+h_2)=f(a,b)+df_{(a,b)}(h_1,h_2)+\|h_1,h_2\|\varepsilon(h_1,h_2)$

with $\lim\limits_{(h_1,h_2)\to(0,0)}\varepsilon(h_1,h_2)=0$